# Json data posting using setHTTPBody is not working in ios

Tags: ios, objective-c, json

I have this code to convert a NSDictonary to jsonbody :

```
    NSString *requestUrl = API_LOCATION;        
    request = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] initWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:requestUrl] cachePolicy:NSURLRequestUseProtocolCachePolicy timeoutInterval:60.0];

   NSError *error = nil;
   NSData *jsonData = [NSJSONSerialization dataWithJSONObject:params
                                                               options:NSJSONWritingPrettyPrinted
                                                                 error:&error];                
   if (! jsonData)
   {
          NSLog(@"jsonStringWithPrettyPrint: error: %@", error.localizedDescription);

   } else
   {
          NSString *jsonString=[[NSString alloc] initWithData:jsonData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
          NSLog(@"%@", jsonString);

          [request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
          [request setValue:@"application/json" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
          [request setHTTPBody:jsonData];
   }
```

From this code I am not getting any output in server side.Though when I log `jsonString` I'm getting :

```
2014-11-13 15:20:46.109 App[2341:60b]{
  "GetUserMasterOperation" : "GetUserMasterOperation",
  "do" : "INSERT",
  "Email" : "dfgdf@gmail.com",
  "UserName" : "rsgdrdsg",
  "Password" : "123",
  "MobileId" : "99D6031D-6A2A-482D-AAFF-332FC4D68795"
}
```

But after converting this string to `NSData` and passing it through `[request setHTTPBody:requestData]`, its not working.

Comment: Why do you rebuild the JSON post data, you can just use the `jsonData` as you HTTP body. No need to create a `NSString` instance and re-encode that.

Comment: @rckoenes:I tried it. But not working. can you tell me how to log the whole HTTPRequest in Objective c before sending it to server?

Comment: No not really, but you can use a proxy like [Charles](http://www.charlesproxy.com) to log all your calls. Also, can you specify what is not working?

Comment: @rckoenes : Yes, I'm sending this jsonbody to the server and in the server end I'm decoding it using `json_decode($_POST)` as it is a PHP page and returning using `return $this->response($this->json(array('stauscode'=>200,'msg'=>$post)), 200);` but no output.

Comment: What does the request return?

Comment: @rckoenes : just the decoded json.

Comment: Just output the response directly and also the status code, this will give you more details and use [Charles](http://www.charlesproxy.com/) proxy to see what is going over the wire. This is all very standaard debuging.

Answer (score 0):

Finally Solved it. Actually this code does not have error...I have a receiving problem of json data in PHP server side.